# Automated deployment of mixed SSIS / DLL solution

Tags: deployment, ssis, automation

We currently have a solution developed using SSIS / C#. The SSIS package (amongst other things) has a script task that uses logic developed in the class libraries. This functionality needs to remain separate from the SSIS package.

Because we are using an SSIS package I understand that the compiled DLL's need to be deployed to the GAC, and then referenced from the script task. However this is creating a deployment problem for us.

Our automated deployment tool (rightly) automatically increments the version numbers of the DLL's, which are then published to the GAC. However this breaks the SSIS package, as it will try and access the DLL's based on the version number they were published to the development machine GAC as.

The only solution we have to this is to get the compiled DLL's, manualy modify the SSIS package script task and then publish the package.

It seems like there must be a better way of doing this - has anyone encountered this problem and come up with a better solution? Or is there something fundamental in our approach we need to change (beyond eliminating the need for the DLL's)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, after much research I never really came up with a satisfactory solution for this. In the end the closest I could get was a solution where I loaded my references dynamically:

```
    Dim rsAssembly As Assembly = Assembly.LoadFile("path from config file")
    Dim rsType As Type = rsAssembly.GetType("class name from config file")
    Dim obj As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(rsType)
```

This allowed me to create the object I required (although worth noting that any other dependant references also need to by dynamically load or part of the GAC, although at least without the dependancy on the version number).

Posted here for future seekers, but if anyone comes up with something better I would still be very curious to know how you resolved it - post here and I will credit you with the answer :)

Answer (score 4):

In my case, just calling `Assembly.LoadFile` didn't work. What did work was this approach:

Call this in the class constructor:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);
```

And then have this method, with all the dlls you need:

```
 private Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
 {
     if (args.Name.Contains("libName.dll"))
         return Assembly.LoadFile(System.IO.Path.Combine(_libraryFolder, "libName.dll"));

     if (args.Name.Contains("libName2.dll"))
         return Assembly.LoadFile(System.IO.Path.Combine(_libraryFolder, "libName2.dll"));

     return null;
 }
```

If they are a lot, you may want to refactor that with a `List<string>`.

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed similar issues with our SSIS/C# mix. We also rely on an external (to SSIS) dll. In our case the DLL had to be copied to the 100/DTS/Binn directory to allow the SSIS package to work from within Visual Studio however when we attempt to run the package using the SQL Package Execution Utility we get an error to the affect that the file could not be found. It does not seem to indicate a version issue so much as a difference in PATH between the Visual Studio and the Package Execution Utility. Even running the package without debug from Visual Studio works. I am going to look into the version issue to see if maybe that is the core complaint on our system but from memory I think it was a file not found type error that affected us. We are using MSSQL 2008 if that makes a difference.

Comment: In followup I was able to execute the package successfully by copying the DLL to the host machines windows\assembly directory. Apparently this is the elusive GAC location? Anyhow our deployment mechanism is not so automated yet so maybe that is why we are not having the version issues. Once I copy the dll to the windows\assembly dir the package runs to completion.

Comment: Hi Travis - yes, that is the location of the GAC, not sure of the restrictions on SQL 2008 but if it helps I can confirm for you that in a deployed server on SQL 2005 the DLL must be deployed to the GAC :(

Answer (score 0):

Are you absolutely sure that those shared DLLs *must* be deployed to the GAC?  If they are in the same folder as the SSIS package, they should be discoverable by the framework without the need to add them to the GAC.

Is there no way to update your build system to avoid the version number change?  If the code of those assemblies is not changing, there is no need to update the version number.

If you can't avoid the version increment, the other alternative is to build a policy file along with the shared assemblies and use that to "redirect" the SSIS package to the new version with each build.

Comment: The information I have is that SSIS packages must be deployed to the GAC, excellent if not - but are you sure? http://www.developerdotstar.com/community/node/333
Build number - I guess we could, but this idea makes me a little uncomfortable. I have not used Policy files before, I will go and have a look at them, thanks

Comment: I haven't tried an SSIS package with external dependencies, so I'm not sure.  Should be fairly easy to build up a mock of your package with the dependency and do a quick smoke test...

Comment: Hi Dave - i've been investigating policy files as they pertain to SSIS solutions, I can't really see how I would go about introducing one without also creating another dependency. I might be missing something, but if you have any additional information on how they can be used with SSIS packages it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Yeah, we tried smoke testing without using the GAC, the approaches we took failed. The only other thing we could think of was using reflection to dynamically load the class from a file location - but that also seems an extreme way to get around this