# how to use a third party dll in ssis package

Tags: c#, .net, dll, ssis

I need to use a third party dll in an SSIS package that I have built.  I know from past work that the DLL has to be registered in the GAC and that requires it to be a strong named assembly.  For the dlls that I have written and used in packages, creating a strong named assembly is easy using a SNK file and compiling the source thus creating the dll.  But how can this be done on a 3rd party dll when I don't have the source.

The target system is Windows Server 2012 which does not have the GacUtil.exe file so I used a Powershell script to do the load.  For the dlls I created I am able to successfully load into the GAC and then see the entry but not for the 3rd party dlls.

Thanks in advance to anyone that can help solve this problem.

Comment: The second half of the answer in the following link may address your question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11611165/add-third-party-dll-reference-in-ssis-script-component

Comment: The link shown in the comment above provided by user3662215 is a link back to this question and there is no answer provided.

Comment: That's odd.  When I select the link first provided, it goes to a different question.  In that stackoverflow link, user billinkc recommended the following given that you do not have access to the DLL source code, "either compile the project in with the source or surround it with a web service wrapper and then reference the service."  This is the one thing he recommends that you have not mentioned having already applied according to your question.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be suitable in your situation, but what I did before is create a console program to wrap the dll, and then in SSIS call this console program from Execute Process Task.